# Is it possible to use same DLL for clients using both Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, linux, dll, window, shared-libraries

I am looking to create a C++ library that can be used by both Linux and Windows clients. The OS specific functionality will be hooked up by the client by implementing the interfaces provided by the library.

Is this possible to achieve? Do I need to recompile the C++ project again in linux.

P.S: I am using CodeBlocks IDE

Comment: It definitively have to be compiled separately for Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no, you still need to compile your library for each targetted platform -- however, assuming your code is written such that it is cross-platform, you can set up your build to target both Windows and Linux environments with little fuss.  I do this now using CMake to generate both Visual Studio projects for Windows environments and Makefiles for Linux environments.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty confident that Linux will not accept a .dll :)  And yes, you will need to recompile.  Unless you run windows as a virtual machine under linux which sort of preempts the question.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly cannot be the same binary file: shared objects ELF format on Linux, DLL "PE" format on Windows. And dynamic loading has different semantics on both systems. See [Levine's linker and loader](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) book for details.

You could, if done carefully, have the same source code giving the two different files (the DLL on Windows, the dynamic shared object on Linux).

<sup>But you probably would need some conditional compilation tricks like `#ifdef WINDOWS` etc...</sup>

You might use libraries providing you a common abstraction for such things. For instance, both GTK/Glib and Qt have some mechanism giving a common abstraction of dynamically linked (or dynamically loaded - ie [dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen)-ed) libraries.

You probably want to read the [Program Library Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) (at least for Linux).